# Guidance for a C# developer to become better UI developer

Tags: c#, html, css, html5

I am a C# developer and had developed simple websites in regular asp.net(with asp.net controls) and a wpf application.

Nowadays, I am trying to learn Asp.net MVC3 and I have been exposed to HTML with the Razor view Engine. To be honest, my knowledge of HTML and CSS is limited. Therefore, I keep posting questions now and then on SO for very simple tasks.

This has made me very tired of the this Q&A development process. So, now i am thinking of learning the basics of HTML, CSS and maybe some Javascript. Therefore i would request you to guide me to become an efficient enough developer for these technologies. Something that won't take much time and get me up and running fast.

Comment: For tips on how to get better at designing things *in general* (may not help you specifically with learning CSS, HTML), go read The Design of Everyday Things: http://www.amazon.com/Design-Everyday-Things-Donald-Norman/dp/0385267746

Comment: If you can wrap your head around a programming language such as C#, HTML and CSS should be easy for you to pick up.

Comment: You should also start frequenting [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Design and implementing a design are different. As Nick has said, learning the technologies are trivial. But remember to learn some graphical design fundamentals, e.g colour wheel and golden ratio vs knowing how to use `!important` CSS.

Comment: Consider checking with http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not going to bother posting links to HTML and CSS tutorials because a quick Google search should turn up hundreds of good resources for this.

I will share with you a tool that was invaluable to myself for learning and debugging CSS in my browser.  If you have Firefox, download an Add-On called Firebug.  It is a neat console that provides amazing features for viewing and real-time editing of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in ANY web page that you visit.  Using this tool I can tinker with stylesheets and styles on specific DOM elements and immediately see the results in my browser.

It also has a built in JavaScript debugger that allows you to write JavaScript expressions as well.  Furthermore I can traverse the elements and attributes of the DOM tree to find neat information that may be hidden.  All of these features are invaluable when doing development in ASP.NET or JSF and you need to debug complicated problems with third-party server controls.  They also help me find neat workarounds.

On top of that, there is a tab for viewing all HTTP requests and responses, allowing you to view the content of any individual request and response as well as headers.

Comment: I haven't used Firebug for a while, but I find that Opera has a great set of development tools already built-in. There are probably plug-in tools as well, but I have never had to look into them.

Comment: http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/features/

Comment: Firefox also has built in console and scratchpad and Chrome has developer tools built-in. But I would stick with FF & Firebug because it has everything and works great.

Comment: Thanks mate...you gave me something new...I always test my apps on Chrome..Will try to install firefox and check it out

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner , mate i haven't seen opera for year now. But, since you seem so confident with it's development tools, I will surely give it a shot. Thanks so much

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: Yeah, Opera's never been popular but it seemed for a long time the new and interesting features that other browsers picked up were already old news in Opera, and I prefer it for my own web browsing, not just the dev tools. If you're doing web development, it's sometimes a good idea to have a number of browsers installed to see how things render across all of them. I haven't done web development for a while, but it used to be standard to test on Opera, Safari, IE, and Firefox (there was no Chrome back then) so they'd all be on my workstation.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : I had divided the browsers in two category : one is chrome, safari, firefox, opera and other is IE(since it does strange things :-P ). Anyways will get the opera up and running today :-)

Answer (score 2):

UI is and is not a technical problem. It is inasmuch as you need to use technical tools to solve things on some levels and the art of the possbible is defined by the platform you are working in. But the biggest thing you can do to make yourself a better UI developer is really to learn how to think of user interfaces from the user's perspective. Remember, your user don't care about:

- Your data model
- Separation of concerns
- Whatever cool toolkit you are using
- Pretty much just about anything else that went into making the UI

Your UI is just a means to an end for them. They do care about doing what they want to do with a minimum of fuss or confusion but little else.

To wit, I'd advise reading up on great user interfaces. A great place to start is Steven Krug's [Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758).

The other thing I really strongly believe in is that developers must use their own user interfaces. The dev team should enter the first 1000 or so records in a system. It is funny how many annoying low-hanging fruit get fixed when that happens. And it is surprising how much you learn from using the things you create that can get pushed into the next creation.

Comment: Having developers use their own user interfaces can have drawbacks. Developers often have a very different idea of how they'd like to use the tool rather than how the client/end user would like to use the tool. So much so that for a current reporting system here, there is a seperate panel so developers get developer-oriented forms (for testing purposes - to be "hidden" in final releases) and reports that the end users have stated they do not like or want.

Comment: Thanks mate. In my own projects, I like to handle the interfaces myself because the pros in this department seem to do too much and annoy. I like keeping things simple and easy to read rather than fancy and outrageous to the eye.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: yes, that is definitely a danger. But I think the potential for good outweighs the downside risk in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Learning a technology from scratch using boards is definitly not an idea I would encourage for non-trivial tasks.

Web page design is significantly different from windows design.

Web design sometimes mean one or more of the following:

A - Web page layout

B - Graphics design

C - User interaction design

D - HTML and CSS coding

E - Java Scripting!

F - Using supporting tools of the above

Each of the above is a different aspect and require special skills. So, identify your role in the project and your objectives from learning first.

I suggest you try a formal design courses. Start with a video course and then move to an instructor lead course.

If you are a programmer focus on the programming of the frameworks and leave the artistic design to other professionals.

If you want to just know about it, then the courses should do it. If you can't do HTML, don't give up. Consider using Silverlight. It is very similar to WPF (at least for the XAML part).

Comment: Silverlight ??, I thought it was basically for replacing flash related stuff. Anyways, thanks for reminding about it, I seemed to have forgotten it :-P . Will visit the website and see how can it help me.